# Replacing multiple parts of a string with switch cases js

Tags: javascript

How would I get the switch to work, such that both cases, when relevant (like below), occur? I can add return to one of the case changes and get it to work for that one, but what if I have multiple cases like below? .replace requires I assign the new value to a new variable....but how do I get that to work in a loop? I don't want to use regex/regular expressions, I want to use a switch as follows, what options do I have to get this to work?

```
function convertText(str) {
  for (let el of str) {
    switch(el) {
      case "&":
        str.replace("&","on") //how to fix this line...?
      case "G":
        str.replace("G","key") //how to fix this line...?
        break;
    }
  }
  return str
}

console.log(convertText("D&G"));
//donkey
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace returns a new string; it does not replace the value in the string you call it on. Maybe what you want is another string variable that you modify and then return, like so:

```
function convertText(str) {
  let result = str;
  for (let el of str) {
    switch(el) {
      case "&":
        result = result.replace("&","on");
        // you may want another break here, unless fall-through is your desired behavior
      case "G":
        result = result.replace("G","key");
        break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(convertText("D&G"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are still using `replace`. But you could take a new string and add the value if a cetain character is found or add the actual character to the result.

```js
function convertText(str) {
    let result = '';
    for (let el of str) {
        switch (el) {
            case "&":
                result += "on";
                break;
            case "G":
                result += "key"
                break;
            default:
                result += el;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(convertText("D&G"));
```